# In R and PostgreSQL, use dbGetQuery to query tables inside schemas

Tags: r, database, postgresql

I'm in `R` trying to run a query on a local Postgres database that has some cable TV provider data in it. Using `DBI::dbGetQuery`, I'm attempting to run a simple query on this database, which has a simple nested tables-inside-schemas sort of structure. Here's my connection code:

```
pg <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(pg, user = "postgres", 
                 password = "password",
                 host = "localhost",
                 port = 5432,
                 dbname = "db1")
```

All good so far -- if I run `dbListTables(con)`, I get the right list of tables.

The tricky part is running the following query:

```
test_get <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from provider.Provider_Composite limit 5;")
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "provider.provider_composite" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from provider.Provider_Composite limit 5;
                      ^
```

If I take the quoted portion of the R command (the actual postgres query, in other words) and paste it right into PGAdmin, for example, it pulls the correct table. But inside the `dbGetQuery` command in `R`, it doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
test_get <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from "provider.Provider_Composite" limit 5;')
```

(single quotes around the statement and double quotes around the table)

Answer (score 1):

You need to double quote the table name because it has upper case letters.

```r
test_get <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from provider."Provider_Composite" limit 5;')
```

The double quotes don't work around the schema.table address as suggested by @nina-van-bruggen. You have to quote each name string individually, if necessary. *For that reason I try to only use lower case names in a PostgreSQL database.*

Comment: Lower-case names: that's really helpful to know, andschar. Since I own the db in question, I'm going to take 15 minutes and make all schemas and tables to avoid snags like this. Related question, since this is my first time doing data analysis from an external SQL db: is it worth my time to have lower-case column names inside tables, too, for similar reasons?

Comment: Yes, avoid upper case and all non-word characters in databases (schemas, tables, columns, ...), because if not, you have to escape them at some point. Imho this is generally (still) a good advice for programming and computers.